# Need help about bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

i need some help about the bash command i use for 3d printing post process script. The command is;

```
curl -k -H "X-Api-Key: 3456AF8E8824F80AE10E46CDFFBE97B" -F "select=false" -F "print=false" -F "file=@[output_filepath]" "http://192.168.1.4/api/files/local"
```

This code works for me until device's ip change.I know the mac address of the device
and i search the ip address of the device with nmap,like;

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0-15  | grep -B 2 60:1F:12:1B:E3:B8| grep report | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

Actually i can write a bash script for that but the software i use for 3d slicing doesn't allow that.(Simplify3D)

How can i solve this,any suggestions?

Comment: Who controls the network? really, a better solution IMHO would be to use a static or DHCP-reserved IP address for the device

Comment: Yes you right but i don't have control over network.

Comment: What exactly does Simplify3D allow and not allow? Do I understand it right you have Simplify3D's output and you need to send it to the printer with changing IP here? If so, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It allows just single line command,i tried to run curl command from bash file but  it didn't work.

Comment: “It does not work” doesn't help at all, please add your *full* script, tell us what the exact prerequisites are and what error messages and odd behaviour you are experiencing. Please always add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) rather than using comments.